# Performance Windows Socket in C++ with Matlab

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, sockets

I am trying to create an application that sends data from a program in C++ to another in Matlab.
The size of the data is ~100 double @ 1000Hz and I am having problems with reaching that frequency (even in localhost).

Using the default parameters of the socket I get ~100Hz. Also I tried using the value TCP_NODELAY to false, but that make it worse. The processor is a i7-2600 @ 3.4 Hz so for sure that is not the problem. Also for the moment the only processing that I am doing with the data is save it, so also there is time consuming process.

Also I am sure that I can reach 1000 Hz because if I delete the send command, the output file has >1000 Hz.

The initialization code:

```
ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
// Initialize Winsock
WSADATA wsaData;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
            *ptr = NULL,
            hints;
int iResult;
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
}
// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Which is mainly (or completly) copy from the Microsoft web page.
For the sending function we have:

```
if (RecordingFlag){
            packet[51]=values[35];
            packet[52]=numchDAQ;
            for (i=0;i<values[35];i++){
                fprintf(file,"%.3lf,",values[i]);
                packet[i] =(double)values[i];
            }
            //DAQ
            if (numchDAQ >0){
                DAQmxReadAnalogF64(taskHandle,1,10.0,DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel,data,16,&read,NULL);
                for(i=0;i<numchDAQ;i++){
                    fprintf(file,"%.3lf,",data[i]);
                    packet[(int)packet[51]+i]=(double)data[i];
                }
            }
            //Timestamp
            GetSystemTime(&st);
            SystemTimeToFileTime(&st,&ft);
            diftime= ((((ULONGLONG) ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime)/10000 - MSEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH;
            fprintf(file,"%llu",diftime);
packet[0]=prueba;
prueba++;
            send( ConnectSocket, (const char*)packet, sizeof(double)*53, 0 );
            fprintf(file,"\n"); 
        }
```

That function is called 1000 times per second.
I guess that the problem is that Windows doesn't create sockets that fast, because is waiting for the ACK from the server. But again, the server in Matlab is also very simple:

```
    import java.net.ServerSocket
    import java.io.*
    j=1;
    i=0;
    server_socket  = [];
    input_socket  = [];
    dataByte = int8(zeros (1,424));
    dataDouble = zeros(10000,53);
    while (1)
        try 
            i= i+1;
            fprintf(1, 'Trying to connect %d\n',i);
            server_socket = ServerSocket(31415);
            server_socket.setSoTimeout(5000); 
            input_socket = server_socket.accept;
            fprintf(1, 'Client connected\n');
            while (1)
                input_stream   = input_socket.getInputStream;
                d_input_stream = DataInputStream(input_stream);
                bytes_available = input_stream.available;
                while(bytes_available>0 && j<10000)
                    %fprintf(1, 'Reading %d bytes\n', bytes_available);
                    for i =1:424
                        dataByte(i)= d_input_stream.readByte;
                        bytes_available = bytes_available-1;
                    end
                    dataDouble(j,:) = typecast(dataByte,'double');
                    j=j+1;
                end
            end

            % cleanup
            input_socket.close;
        catch
            if ~isempty(server_socket)
                server_socket.close;
            end

            if ~isempty(input_socket)
                input_socket.close
            end

            % pause before retrying
            %pause(1);
        end
   end
```

Even without make the typecast I get the same results.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

EDIT: The problem was in Matlab, it read the information too slowly. I changed the code and now works perfectly
    while(bytes_available>0 && j<1000)
        d_input_stream.read(dataByte,0,424);
        bytes_available = bytes_available-424;
        dataDouble(j,:) = typecast(dataByte,'double');
        j=j+1;
    end

Comment: You don't want to be trying to create 1000 sockets a second. Just create one socket and keep it open while streaming the data over it.

Comment: I express my self incorrectly. I'm not creating 1000 sockets. I create one and try to send 1000 packets per second.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Matlab, it read the information too slowly. I changed the code and now works perfectly

```
while(bytes_available>0 && j<1000)
    d_input_stream.read(dataByte,0,424);
    bytes_available = bytes_available-424;
    dataDouble(j,:) = typecast(dataByte,'double');
    j=j+1;
end
```

– Priack